# How can someone figure out my root password?

Tags: php, security, server, passwords

Today someone hacked my server and logged in as Root user.
I have a very complex password, made from 8 characters, numbers and its case sensitive.

How from technical point is possible for someone to find out my root password? Can someone log in as Root user from some apache service or php without entering actual password?

Comment: You should include in your description if it is shared hosting or not.

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you ask this question on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your password is not very complex, you should not allow the `root` user to login you should use another username or a root SSH key

Comment: An 8 character password can be broken with brute force very quickly. It is one reason why I started a campaign [to remove password limits](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use just a pure password. SSH keys are your friend

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question belongs on SO, but I think you could use a little direction anyway.

## Check your assumptions

You should start with checking your assumptions:

> Today someone hacked my server and logged in as Root user.

How do you know? Is there an entry in the log file that showed a user logging in from an unknown IP address?  When you say `logged in`, most of us will assume you mean logged in using either ssh, or maybe some kind of management interface like cpanel. We interpret this as "someone gained access using valid credentials". However, you don't have to have valid credentials to access a site.

If the only evidence you have is that someone changed some files, then you can't really be sure they "logged in" at all.  If they exploited a service on you webserver, they could alter and edit files without ever knowing your password. This occurs quite regularly with unpatched and unmaintained joomla and wordpress instances (among others).

## Stealing Passwords

> How from technical point is possible for someone to find out my root password? Can someone log in as Root user from some apache service or php without entering actual password?

See above for the "log in" discussion. But to be clear, yes, someone could run as root or php without actually logging in, or using the password. Consider that they could also steal your password using a keylogger on the client you are logging in from, or, if they had previously compromised your server, installing programs on the server to capture your password.

If you are using a web based administration, then the attacker could also leverage attacks like cross site scripting or cross site request forgery to either steal your session cookies or preform actions on your behalf.

## The bottom line

Recovering from a compromise can be very tricky. You have to collect a lot of data to attempt to determine the cause. You should review your web logs, ssh logs, etc. Put together a timeline, when did the files change, who was the last user to log in, etc. You also have to ensure the intruders are gone: did you restore your files from a known good backup? Are there any extra startup processes or cronjobs?